# center all grid items in the middle with even spaces

Tags: css, reactjs

Trying to evenly space out all grid items in the middle of the page:

[image]

App Component:

````
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App__box">
        <Box />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```


App Css:

    .App {
      $large-screen: 1024px;
      $xlarge-screen: 1280px;
    
      text-align: center;
    
      &__box {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        grid-gap: 16px 16px;
      }
    
      @media (min-width: $large-screen) {
        &__box {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr);
          justify-items: center;
        }
      }
    }

Ps the desired outcome i am trying to achive for the `$large-screen` breakpoint
````

Answer (score 0):

fix the with with max-width property
then give it
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question, it's possible by using `justify-self` and `nth-child`. see code:

```css
 .boxes {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 2fr);
     grid-gap: 16px 16px;
 }
 .box {
     width: 10rem;
     padding: 1rem;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: red;
     justify-self: end;
 }
 .box:nth-child(2) {
       background-color: blue;
       justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
     <div class="boxes">
          <div class="box">1</div>
          <div class="box">2</div>
          <div class="box">3</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a

```
{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and try out `justify-content` prop for parent component, and for child components could use `flex-grow` prop.

Check out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox